# Sectional curvature of Hadamard manifolds vanishes along certain planes if exponential map preserves norm

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I've been trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $M$ be a Hadamard manifold (simply connected, complete and with sectional curvature $K \leq 0$). Show that:
>
> **i)** Let $p \in M, v, w \in T_pM$ linearly independent, $\gamma_v$ the geodesic with initial condition $v$, and $E_w$ the parallel vector field along $\gamma_v$ with $E_w(0) = w$. If $\|\mathrm{d}(\exp_p)_v(w)\| = \|w\|$, then $K(\gamma_v'(t), E_w(t)) = 0$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$.
>
> **ii)** Every metric ball $B_r(p)$ in $M$, $r \geq 0$, is strictly convex, i.e every geodesic segment connecting two points of $B_r(p)$ is contained in $B_r(p)$.

But I haven't had any good ideas so far. I know the exponential map is a global diffeomorphism in this case and I think maybe some solution could come from using Jacobi fields/variations but I couldn't think of anything concrete along those lines. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Since Hadamard manifolds don't have any conjugate points, I see now how **i)** is a straightforward consequence of Rauch's comparison theorem. I'm still stuck on **ii)** though and I realize now I should've split it into two posts, so I'm going to ask it in another post.

Comment: I spent a lot of times trying to prove i). For now, what I have shown is that the plane generated by $\gamma'$ and $\mathrm{d}\exp_p(tv)\cdot w$ always has $0$ sectional curvature, but I did't manage to show that this latter vector field is colinear to $E_w(t)$. I guess I'm missing the trick.

Comment: @Didier any help is appreciated! I tried but didn't get that far. I'd appreciate it if you could post your efforts in an answer (and edit it later if you manage to get farther), if no one else makes any progress for a while I can accept it.

Comment: Right now, it's late in the night here, but I'll put something tomorrow if that can help

Comment: @Didier Alright! It will most definitely help, looking forward to it

Comment: Did you already learn Rauch Comparison Theorem (RCT)? If so, use it to prove (i). Proof of (ii) is trickier, you need to derive some consequences from RCT first and not every textbook does it. What textbook are you reading?

Comment: Thanks @MoisheKohan! I see now how i) follows from RCT. But could you explain what are these consequences you mention? I don't remember any that could help. I'm reading Do Carmo's book (and also supplementing it with Lee's book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer but definitely too long for a comment. I'll edit this whenever something new comes up. Any hint, help or comment is appreciated.

**Question i)**
We consider $(M,g)$ a Riemannian manifold.
Define $\gamma(t) = \exp_p(tv)$, (suppose $\|v\|=1$ for convinience) and  $Y(t) = \mathrm{d}\exp_p(tv)\cdot tw$. It is well known that $Y$ is a Jacobi field along $\gamma$, that is:
$$
Y'' =-R_{\gamma'}Y \left(:=  -R(\gamma',Y)\gamma'\right),
$$
and that it is the unique one satisfying $Y(0) = 0, Y'(0) = w$.
You may have another convention for $R$, but what is important is that $g\left(R_{\gamma'}X,X\right) = \sec(\gamma',X)\|X\|^2$.

Finally, we suppose that $M$ is Hadamard, (and it follows that $Y(t) \neq 0$ if $t \neq 0$) and that $\|Y(1)\| = \|w\|$.

*Step 1.* Let $f(t) = \|Y(t)\|$ for $t\in [0,1]$. Then $f$ is a convex function. Indeed, $f$ is smooth whenever $Y \neq 0$, thus is smooth on $]0,1]$. Moreover, on $]0,1]$:
\begin{align}
f' &= \frac{g(Y',Y)}{\|Y\|} \\
f'' &= \frac{\left(g(Y'',Y) + \|Y'\|^2 \right)\|Y\| - g(Y',Y)  \frac{g(Y',Y)}{\|Y\|}}{\|Y\|^2} \\
&= \frac{-\sec(\gamma',Y) \|Y\|^4 + \|Y'\|^2\|Y\|^2 - g(Y',Y)^2}{\|Y\|^3}\\
&= -\sec(\gamma',Y)\|Y\| + \frac{\|Y'\|^2\|Y\|^2 - g(Y',Y)^2}{\|Y\|^3}.
\end{align}
From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, the last term is $\geqslant 0$, and from the Hadamard hypothesis, $\sec(\gamma',Y) \leqslant 0$, hence:
$$f'' \geqslant 0,$$
and $f$ is convex.

*Step 2.* We have an upper bound on $f$. It is clear that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = \|w\|$. By convexity:
$$
\forall t \in [0,1], f(t) \leqslant (1-t)f(0) + tf(1) = t\|w\|,
$$
hence, $f(t) \leqslant t \|w\|$.

*Step 3.* This latter inequality is an equality. To see this, define:
$$
h(t) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(t)}{t\|w\|} & \text{if } t>0 \\ 1 & \text{if } t =0 \end{cases}.
$$
Then $h$ is continuous (because $Y(t) \sim_0 tY'(0)$), smooth on $]0,1]$, and:
$$
h'(t) = \frac{tf'(t) - f(t)}{t^2\|w\|}.
$$
Write $tf'(t) - f(t) = tf'(t) - f(t) - (0\times f'(0) - f(0))= \int_0^t \left(sf'(s) - f(s)\right)'\mathrm{d}s = \int_0^t sf''(s)\mathrm{d}s$. It follows, from the convexity of $f$, that $h' \geqslant 0$. Hence, $h$ is non-decreasing and:
$$
\forall t \in [0,1], h(t) \geqslant h(0) = 1
$$
that is:
$$
\forall t \in [0,1], f(t) \geqslant t\|w\|.
$$
Finally, $f(t) = t\|w\|$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

*Step 4.* $\forall t \in ]0,1]$, $\sec(\gamma'(t),Y(t)) = 0$. Indeed, $f$ is linear, hence $f''=0$. it follows that:
$$
0 = f'' = -\sec(\gamma',Y)\|Y\| + \frac{\|Y'\|^2\|Y\|^2 - g(Y',Y)^2}{\|Y\|^3}\geqslant 0
$$
and as all terms are $\geqslant 0$ on the RHS, we can conclude that $\sec(\gamma',Y) = 0$.

Note that we are in presence of the equality case in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and we can therefore claim that $Y(t)$ and $Y'(t)$ are linearly dependant.

From now, I cannot conclude that $Y$ is colinear to $E_w(t)$, the parallel transport of $w$ along $\gamma$ ; it seems natural in this case, but I guess I'm missing the trick.

**Update 1.**

We have already shown that $Y'$ and $Y$ are colinear. Hence, there exists $\alpha$, a function defined on $(0,1]$, with $Y' = \alpha Y$. Differentiating this equality gives:
$$
Y'' = (\alpha' + \alpha^2)Y,
$$
and taking the scalar product with $Y$ gives, recalling that $\sec(\gamma',Y) = 0$:
$$
\alpha' + \alpha^2 = 0
$$
It follows that $\alpha(t) = \frac{1}{t - c_0}$ for a constant $c_0$. The initial data give $c_0=0$, *i.e* $\alpha(t) = \frac{1}{t}$.

**Summary of what we have shown for now**.

- the function $t \in [0,1] \mapsto \|Y(t)\|$ is linear
- $\forall t\in [0,1], ~\sec(\gamma'(t),Y(t)) = 0$
- $\forall t \in [0,1]~, tY'(t) = Y(t)$